# Django i18n Problems

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, internationalization

I have a Django 1.8 project that I would like to internationalize. I have added the code to do so in the application, and when I change the `LANGUAGE_CODE` tag, I can successfully see the other language used, but when I leave it on `en-us`, no other languages show up. I have changed my computer's language to the language in question (German), but calls to the site are still in English. What am I doing wrong?

Other things:

- `USE_I18N = true`
- `LOCALE_PATHS` works correctly (since changing the
  `LANGUAGE_CODE` works)
- I have also tried settings the `LANGUAGES` attribute although I don't think I have to anyway.

EDIT: I have also confirmed that the GET call has the header: `Accept-Language:de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4`, which contains `de` like I want. My `locale` folder has a folder `de` in it.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to add`'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware'` to my `settings.py` file in the `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` section. I figured if internationalization was already on that this wouldn't be necessary.